# Correct method to output \' and other escape characters to HTML

Tags: php, jquery, html

I currently have a jquery function that has pre-written strings stored in them like this:

```
$('#message').val("Your parts have been ordered. We'll let you know when we receive the parts and begin installing them.");
```

When I click a button, it will take the string and fill it in a `textarea` to make filling out a form easier. It fills the `textarea` with the correct information and looks great on the actual form elements.

However when I'm sending the message to the client using PHPs mail function, at every `'`, `"`, and other special character it's inserting a `\` before the character, so it will output like this:

> Your parts have been ordered. We\'ll let you know when we receive the parts and begin installing them.

Is there a built in function that I can run the variables through before sending the email?

I've been doing some research and the closest thing I found is PHPs `htmlspecialchars` function, but this does the exact opposite of what I'm trying to accomplish.

---

Getting POST variable:

`$commentmessage = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['message']);`

Setting Headers for email (might be relevant because I'm formatting it using a table):

```
$headers = "From: Repairs@email.com \r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: ". $useremail . "\r\n";
$headers .= "CC: myemail@email.com \r\n";$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
```

Creating Message:

```
$emailmessage = wordwrap($emailmessage, 100, "\r\n");

$emailmessage = '<html><body>';
$emailmessage .= '<img src="imageurl" alt="Logo" />';
$emailmessage .= '<table rules="all" border="1" style="border-color: #666;" cellpadding="10">';
$emailmessage .= "<tr style='background: #eee;'><th colspan='2'><strong>" . $commentSubject ."</strong></th></tr>";
$emailmessage .= "<tr><td>" . $commentmessage . "</td></tr>";
$emailmessage .= "<tr><td><b>Ticket #: </b>" . $ticketid . "</td></tr>";
$emailmessage .= "</table>";
$emailmessage .= "</body></html>";
// Send Mail By PHP Mail Function
if (mail($to, $subject, $emailmessage, $headers)) {
    $message = "Your mail has been sent successfully!";
} 
else {
    $message = "Failed to send email, try again.";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For PHP you have a built-in function: [stripslashes()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php).

Comment: That's worked like a charm.  Thanks for your help.  I didn't know of that function.  I'm sure I'll be using it a lot in the future!

Comment: You are welcome, just remember to see the list of functions in the URL I gave you, on the right side, there are a lot of useful built-in strings PHP's functions